# How to fix this code? It writes to file the first argument, why not the second?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am working on this code to automate "copy-paste" by reading from an access table and write to excel sheet. 
Different values from access table, needs to be written in a particular cells on excel sheet.
My problem is that the code works by reading and writing the first value, but not the second++ values.

The first value is correctly written on E15 in Excel, but the second value which is supposed to be written on cell E16 is not written, Why?

```
Sub HentData()

Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim Sum As Double

DBFullName = "C:\saga_effekt_Nidaros_2017_tiltak.mdb"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set TargetRange = Sheets("1.3 Persontransportmodell").Range("A1")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\saga_effekt_Nidaros_2017_tiltak.mdb;"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [REISEMIDDE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'sum'", cn, , , adCmdText

For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    'TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

TargetRange.Offset(14, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [REISEMIDDE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'referansetrafikk'", cn, , , adCmdText

For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    'TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

TargetRange.Offset(15, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I dont get any error messages, the code runs, but the output is not complete.

Comment: You have an `Exit Sub` statement which will end the processing earlier than you need it to...

Comment: And the `Exit Sub` seems unnecessary

Comment: And since you have closed and set to Nothing both your Connection and Recordset objects, the code will fail when you take the Exit Sub out.  You should step through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: first, use `Option Explicit` to declare all variables

Comment: If I take away Exit Sub, I get an error on my second rs.open that says "operation is not allowed when the object is open"

Comment: @AdrianA, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an edit to your original code that should work. There was no need to call the first `Exit Sub`. The second was also unnecessary since you did not have any error-handling code.

Also, you do not need to close the connection or discard `rs` until the end.

```
Sub HentData()

Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim Sum As Double

DBFullName = "C:\saga_effekt_Nidaros_2017_tiltak.mdb"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set TargetRange = Sheets("1.3 Persontransportmodell").Range("A1")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\saga_effekt_Nidaros_2017_tiltak.mdb;"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [REISEMIDDE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'sum'", cn, , , adCmdText

For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    'TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next
TargetRange.Offset(14, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
On Error GoTo 0

rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [REISEMIDDE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'referansetrafikk'", cn, , , adCmdText

For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    'TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next
TargetRange.Offset(15, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to use this code to add 2 different values from rs.open for f.eks the sum of  [VERDI] for the variabels 'test1' +'test2' before writing the sum of them to excel, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
range(cells(15,4), cells(15,3+rs.Fields.Count)).CopyFromRecordset rs
```